# How to access default automatic colors in gnuplot?

Tags: colors, plot, gnuplot

When you do a plot without explicitly giving color names/values, then gnuplot chooses some pretty ones for you. So,

```
plot x, x*x
```

will be in two different colors. **How can I access these color values?**

I want to plot two functions, and use a different axis for each, and each axis label should be the same color as the function - but I want to use the default colors automatically (because I don't have time and art skills to find out good colors by myself). So basically I'm looking for a command option/variable similiar to

```
set y2label 'y2-axis' textcolor SAME_AS_PLOT_AUTOMATIC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of the labels can be controlled with the `textcolor` option which can also take an integer number which specifies the color of the respective line type:

```
set ylabel 'First axis' textcolor lt 1
set y2label 'Second axis' textcolor lt 2
plot x, x**2 axes x1y2
```

Comment: This gives me `colorspec option not recognized`. The color parameters (like `textcolor`) expect something like `rgbcolor <color>`, `variable` or `palette`.

Comment: Ok, couldn't test it at the moment. I think you must add `lt`: `set ylabel 'First axis' textcolor lt 1`.

Comment: Ah, yes, adding `lt` changes the color. But `tc lt 1` is not the same color as `plot x with points`. I'm plotting `with points` - I'd expected the points to have the same colors as the lines, but apparently they don't. Edit, tested: Nope, plotting `with lines` gives different colors as well (`tc lt 1` is a different color than one gets with `plot x`).

Comment: Do you use `set style increment user` somewhere in your script? Using only the three lines given in my answer works as expected with 4.6.5.

Comment: No, I don's use any `set style` stuff. I'm using version 5rc1 64bit on Windows 8.1. Using `set term svg`, if that's important. If I try your three lines, output into svg, I get four different colors (axis labels and functions, all have different colors). Edit: Qt terminal (default) also 4 different colors.

Comment: Wow, that Looks like a nice bug... If you use `textcolor ls 1` it works fine with 5.0rc1. I'll report this bug.

Comment: Yes, you are right, with `ls 1` it works. Thank you very much. :) (if you mention this bug in your answer, this will be best, I think)

Comment: I reported the bug: [#1452 Textcolor linetype selects wrong colors](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1452/).